# The meaning of 『カン』 and 気配の察知

Tags: meaning, words, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

A character is talking about his abilities in the Adventurer's Guild. I don't understand what does these terms means here. (『カン』 and 気配の察知, i guess he meant "6th sense" but not sure )

> 俺はまだ若いから、生意気だ、世の中を舐めているとよく言われる。まあ実際、その通りだ。
>
> だが、俺の実力が冒険者ギルドで飛び抜けていたのは紛れもない事実で、俺に比肩するヤツはいない。
>
> 危険を察知する**『カン』**にしてもそうだ。観察眼や想像力、推理、機転、気配の察知。こうした能力でも、俺は超一流だ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This カン is [勘](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8B%98) in kanji. "6th sense" is one of its possible translations, but rather than some supernatural ability, it basically refers to a type of "perception" everyone has (people say あの人は勘がいい/悪い but not あの人には勘がある/ない). It broadly refers to instinct, intuition, hunch, and even random guess. Depending on the context, 勘がいい人 may refer to someone who can dodge bullets using their animal-like instincts, someone who can see through another person's lies intuitively, or someone who is good at games like blackjack.

気配の察知 in a context like this refers to perceiving the presence of a (hidden) person/animal. In some fictional works, such as *Dragon Ball*, 気配 may refer to something akin to "aura" or "qi" that is constantly emitted by lifeforms. But when an ordinary person like me says 誰かの気配がする, it may actually refer to things like subtle breathing sounds or pure hunch.

See also: [What is the sense of 気配がする (けはいがする) versus 気がする?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/980/5010)